# SQL Cluster - using datasource (local)

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing

Using (local) in the connection string doesn't work on my cluster.  I'm assuming it's looking for the default instance on the currently active node instead of the Virtual SQL name.  Anyone know how to make this work?

edit note: 
I'd like to use (local) and not localhost - I don't want to change any application generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names (local) or (.) will always use the shared memory interface, rather than TCP or Named Pipes, and neither can be used against a clustered instance which requires TCP or Named Pipes over TCP. You can't use the shared memory interface against a non-local instance, which in the case of a cluster, the instance may or may not be local.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the clustered Virtual SQL Service name, unfortunately localhost and (local) do not work on a cluster

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "localhost" without ( and )

Comment: Certain programs use (local), which is a sql connection string keyword apparently.  My goal is to not have to get into the vendor supplied application and change it, otherwise I would just change it to the virtual SQL name.

Comment: i know (local) only when you try to access an special instance.
the cluster works on his virtual ip.